# Environment makes unnecessary page break

Tags: math-mode, page-breaking, environments

I have a problem with user-defined environments in LaTeX. Even though the content of an environment seems to fit, sometimes LaTeX makes an unneccessary page break after all.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}



\newenvironment{testenviron}
{}
{}



\begin{document}
\begin{testenviron}
Irgendein Text\dots

\vspace{17.5cm}

\dots und am Ende eine Formel:
\[f(x)=x\]
\end{testenviron}
\end{document}
```

To keep it simple, the environment has an empty pre- and postcode. Furthermore `\vspace{17.5cm}` stands for any text of this length. But for some inexplicable reason pdfLaTeX puts an empty page after that. So my question is: What I am doing wrong and what I am misunderstanding? If I write the pre- and postcode directly without using environments, no further page appears - that's kinda strange.

Comment: `\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}` solves the problem, but this is not that consistent.

Comment: See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX#Extra_space . Instead of `\newenvironment{testenviron} {} {}` use `\newenvironment{testenviron} {\noindent\ignorespaces} {\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inserting the replacement text (an empty group `{}`) for your `testenviron` at both `\begin{testenviron}` and `\end{testenviron}`, you obtain the same result. My assumption is that you just commented out these lines, which lead to a 1-page document.

Ending your environment with a display equation causes any `\end{testenviron}` content to be set on a new line, even if it's an empty group.

How would you fix it? This depends on what you include in `testenviron`, or whether you usually end your environment with a display equation. Easiest, in this instance would be to ignore the empty space at the end using

```
\newenvironment{testenviron}
  {}% \begin{testenviron}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}% \end{testenviron}
```

Comment: Thank you for your further explanation. This solved my problem.