# \newenvironment creating an extra page

Tags: environments

The following code produces:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[centering,marginparwidth=2in]{geometry}
\evensidemargin 1.5in
\oddsidemargin 1.5in
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{exotmp}{%
\begingroup
  \begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{-1.5in}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2fil}
  }% 
  \item%
}
{\end{list}%
\endgroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction to Problem Solving}
\lipsum[2]
\section{The Problem-Solving Process and Strategies}
\lipsum[4-7]
\section{Three Additional Strategies}
\lipsum[5-12]
\begin{exotmp}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-9]
\end{multicols}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
\item \lipsum[2-3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{exotmp}
\end{document}
```

Evidently there is something wrong as an extra page is produced. Can any one explain why this is happening and how to re-write the command so that it stops behaving in that manner?

Comment: does this help: [environment-makes-unnecessary-page-break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78546/environment-makes-unnecessary-page-break)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multicol has to make a guess as to whether it should start a new page or if ther eis room on the current page. Just after `\item` makes that tricky as there is a lot of pending activity at that point. removing the spurious group, adding some ingorespaces and putting in an emty box to terminate the item makes things more stable.

```
\newenvironment{exotmp}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{-1.5in}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2fil}
  }% 
  \item\mbox{}\ignorespaces
}
{\end{list}\ignorespacesafterend}
```

Comment: Can the space created above the environment (at the beginning) be avoided. As it is, it creates an extra space right?

Comment: yes you could \vspace*{-\baselineskip} after the item it depends a bit what the intention of the code is

Comment: As is, the geometry of the page is defined and I created this environment to leave this geometry and work temporarily on it.

Comment: I was thinking of defining the same environment with geometry like: `\newenvironment{exotmp}{%
\newgeometry{bottom=1.5in}
\mbox{}\ignorespaces
}
{\restoregeometry\ignorespacesafterend}` but I can't find how to create the same effect (margin definitions) as what the given environment in my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the group from your definition:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[centering,marginparwidth=2in]{geometry}
\evensidemargin 1.5in
\oddsidemargin 1.5in
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{exotmp}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{-1.5in}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2fil}
  }% 
  \item%
}
{\end{list}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction to Problem Solving}
\lipsum[2]
\section{The Problem-Solving Process and Strategies}
\lipsum[4-7]
\section{Three Additional Strategies}
\lipsum[5-12]
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5cm}
\begin{exotmp}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2-9]
\end{multicols}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
\item \lipsum[2-3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{exotmp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the same results.

Comment: @azetina With my example code?